# Async file/image uploading failure after first requests in Java Sprint Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, file-upload

this is my first ever post on StackOverflow, so I hope I'm doing it correctly. Thanks in advance!

I'm refactoring a file uploading function to an Async file uploading function.
I am able to create a traileroffer,then with another POST request I can upload images to it. If I restart the application everything is uploading successfully 100% of the time. After any type of request, the image uploading fails, sometimes a couple will go through successfully.

The main issue is, it seems that the files which are uploaded are empty / the file size is <= 0. I'm not sure what's going wrong but before I refactor my entire (working) function I'd like to check if this may be a project based thing or if it's more complicated than that.

The reason I think my post differentiates others is that my function/code is probably fine, but it may be something in my project setup instead. I hope someone experienced something similar like me and knows what may be the cause. Though, it may be my code/function because before I refactored to Asynchronous, it did work fine.

```
 @PostMapping(path = "/{trailerId}/images", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> addTrailerImages(@PathVariable UUID trailerId, @Valid @ModelAttribute SaveImagesDTO saveImagesDTO) {
        TrailerOffer trailer = trailerOfferService.getTrailerOffer(trailerId);
 MultipartFile[] coverImages = saveImagesDTO.getCoverImage();
        MultipartFile[] images = saveImagesDTO.getImages();

        MultipartFile[] combinedImagesArray = new MultipartFile[coverImages.length + images.length];

        System.arraycopy(coverImages, 0, combinedImagesArray, 0, coverImages.length);
        System.arraycopy(images, 0, combinedImagesArray, coverImages.length, images.length);

        CompletableFuture<ImageUploadResult> imagesFuture = imageService.uploadImagesAsync(combinedImagesArray,"trailer", trailer);

        imagesFuture.handle((result, ex) -> {
            if (ex != null) {
                System.out.println("Exception in CompletableFuture: " +ex);
            } else {
                Image coverImage = result.getCoverImage();
                List<Image> addedImages = result.getAddedImages();

                trailer.setCoverImage(coverImage);
                trailerOfferService.saveTrailerOffer(trailer);
            }

            return result;
        });

        return ResponseEntity.accepted().build();
    }
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SaveImagesDTO {
    private MultipartFile[] coverImage;
    private MultipartFile[] images;
}
```

```
 @Async
    public CompletableFuture<ImageUploadResult> uploadImagesAsync(MultipartFile[] files, String directory, TrailerOffer trailer) {
        try {
            if (files == null || files.length == 0) {
                System.out.println("No files received for trailer ID: " + trailer.getId());
                return CompletableFuture.failedFuture(new IllegalArgumentException("No files received"));
            }

            for(MultipartFile file : files){
                if(file.isEmpty() || file.getSize() <= 0){
                    System.out.println("IMAGESERVICE - FAILED files are empty.");
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Received: " + files.length + " images " + " for trailer id: " + trailer.getId());

            List<Image> images = uploadImages(files, directory, trailer);
            log.debug("Successfully processed {} images for trailer ID: {}", images.size(), trailer.getId());

            ImageUploadResult result = new ImageUploadResult();
            result.setCoverImage(images.get(0));
            result.setAddedImages(images.subList(1, images.size()));
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error processing images for trailer ID: {}", trailer.getId(), e);
            return CompletableFuture.failedFuture(e);
        }
    }
```

```
 public List<Image> uploadImages(MultipartFile[] files, String directory, TrailerOffer trailer) throws NotAnImageException, GCPFileUploadException, BadRequestException, FileWriteException {
        List<Image> images = new ArrayList<>();

        Arrays.asList(files).forEach(file -> {
            String originalFileName = file.getOriginalFilename();

            if (originalFileName == null) {
                throw new BadOriginalFileNameException();
            }

            System.out.println("Adding new image to trailer: " + originalFileName);
            images.add(new Image(originalFileName, trailer));
        });

        imageRepository.saveAll(images);

        for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
            MultipartFile file = Arrays.asList(files).get(i);
            System.out.println("NU TEST: " + file.getSize());
            Image image = images.get(i);
            System.out.println("Uploading image(" + i + "): " + images.get(i).getOriginalFileName());
            dataBucketUtil.uploadFile(file, image.getId(), directory);
        }

        for (Image image : images) {
            image.setPublicUrl(getPublicUrl(image, directory));
            imageRepository.save(image);
        }

        return images;
    }
```

```
    @Async
    public void uploadFile(MultipartFile multipartFile, UUID id, String directory) throws GCPFileUploadException, NotAnImageException, BadRequestException, FileWriteException {
        String fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
        System.out.println("Start file uploading process on GCS for fileName: " + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename() + " id: " + id);

        try {
            String fileExtension = checkFileExtension(fileName);
            String contentType = getContentType(fileName);
            System.out.println(fileName + ": File extension: " + fileExtension);
            System.out.println(fileName + ": Content type: " + contentType);

            if (multipartFile.isEmpty() || multipartFile.getSize() == 0) {
              //  throw new GCPFileUploadException("[FAILED] Uploaded file is empty or size is 0");
                System.out.println("[FAILED] Uploaded file is empty or size is 0");
            }

            System.out.println(fileName+": Size: " + multipartFile.getSize());

            if (!multipartFile.isEmpty() && multipartFile.getSize() > 0) {
                byte[] fileData = multipartFile.getBytes();
                Bucket bucket = getBucket();
                bucket.create(DIR_NAME + "/" + directory + "/" + id + fileExtension, fileData, contentType);
                System.out.println(fileName+": SUCCESS uploaded successfully");
            } else {
                System.out.println(fileName+": [FAILED] File size is 0 or file is empty.");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("An error occurred while uploading data. Exception: ", e);
            throw new GCPFileUploadException("An error occurred while storing data to GCS: " + e);
        }
    }
```

Successfull logs:

```
Received: 4 images  for trailer id: 752c5347-8f69-4d63-a119-a4d370e0c5cb
Adding new image to trailer: Achterkant.jpg
Adding new image to trailer: Klein.png
Adding new image to trailer: Zijkant.jpg
Adding new image to trailer: Hoofdfoto.jpg
NU TEST: 9456
Uploading image(0): Achterkant.jpg
NU TEST: 125435
Uploading image(1): Klein.png
NU TEST: 10599
Uploading image(2): Zijkant.jpg
NU TEST: 46161
Uploading image(3): Hoofdfoto.jpg
Start file uploading process on GCS for fileName: Achterkant.jpg id: 18ef6ca2-297b-449e-b61b-6e04447a9f54
Start file uploading process on GCS for fileName: Klein.png id: 13673f73-0d6c-463e-a1b6-d7ac593a4749
Start file uploading process on GCS for fileName: Hoofdfoto.jpg id: c0bba919-5838-46e8-8a18-d3ceb0e813e1
Start file uploading process on GCS for fileName: Zijkant.jpg id: ff14cbdf-a844-4f94-91aa-b6225506724e
Achterkant.jpg: File extension: .jpg
Klein.png: File extension: .png
Hoofdfoto.jpg: File extension: .jpg
Zijkant.jpg: File extension: .jpg
Achterkant.jpg: Content type: image/jpeg
Zijkant.jpg: Content type: image/jpeg
Hoofdfoto.jpg: Content type: image/jpeg
Klein.png: Content type: image/png
Zijkant.jpg: Size: 10599
Klein.png: Size: 125435
Hoofdfoto.jpg: Size: 46161
Achterkant.jpg: Size: 9456
Achterkant.jpg: SUCCESS uploaded successfully
Zijkant.jpg: SUCCESS uploaded successfully
Hoofdfoto.jpg: SUCCESS uploaded successfully
Klein.png: SUCCESS uploaded successfullyReceived: 4 images  for trailer id: 752c5347-8f69-4d63-a119-a4d370e0c5cb
Adding new image to trailer: Achterkant.jpg
Adding new image to trailer: Klein.png
Adding new image to trailer: Zijkant.jpg
Adding new image to trailer: Hoofdfoto.jpg
NU TEST: 9456
Uploading image(0): Achterkant.jpg
NU TEST: 125435
Uploading image(1): Klein.png
NU TEST: 10599
Uploading image(2): Zijkant.jpg
NU TEST: 46161
Uploading image(3): Hoofdfoto.jpg
Start file uploading process on GCS for fileName: Achterkant.jpg id: 18ef6ca2-297b-449e-b61b-6e04447a9f54
Start file uploading process on GCS for fileName: Klein.png id: 13673f73-0d6c-463e-a1b6-d7ac593a4749
Start file uploading process on GCS for fileName: Hoofdfoto.jpg id: c0bba919-5838-46e8-8a18-d3ceb0e813e1
Start file uploading process on GCS for fileName: Zijkant.jpg id: ff14cbdf-a844-4f94-91aa-b6225506724e
Achterkant.jpg: File extension: .jpg
Klein.png: File extension: .png
Hoofdfoto.jpg: File extension: .jpg
Zijkant.jpg: File extension: .jpg
Achterkant.jpg: Content type: image/jpeg
Zijkant.jpg: Content type: image/jpeg
Hoofdfoto.jpg: Content type: image/jpeg
Klein.png: Content type: image/png
Zijkant.jpg: Size: 10599
Klein.png: Size: 125435
Hoofdfoto.jpg: Size: 46161
Achterkant.jpg: Size: 9456
Achterkant.jpg: SUCCESS uploaded successfully
Zijkant.jpg: SUCCESS uploaded successfully
Hoofdfoto.jpg: SUCCESS uploaded successfully
Klein.png: SUCCESS uploaded successfully
```

Error logs:

```
IMAGESERVICE - FAILED files are empty.
Received: 4 images  for trailer id: 752c5347-8f69-4d63-a119-a4d370e0c5cb
Adding new image to trailer: Achterkant.jpg
Adding new image to trailer: Klein.png
Adding new image to trailer: Zijkant.jpg
Adding new image to trailer: Hoofdfoto.jpg
NU TEST: 0
Uploading image(0): Achterkant.jpg
NU TEST: 0
Uploading image(1): Klein.png
Start file uploading process on GCS for fileName: Achterkant.jpg id: ead6e44a-57d5-467f-b191-7ce590f94d7b
NU TEST: 0
Uploading image(2): Zijkant.jpg
Start file uploading process on GCS for fileName: Klein.png id: 3113e5dd-eff7-4620-9f61-65792bd556ed
Achterkant.jpg: File extension: .jpg
Achterkant.jpg: Content type: image/jpeg
NU TEST: 0
Uploading image(3): Hoofdfoto.jpg
[FAILED] Uploaded file is empty or size is 0
Klein.png: File extension: .png
Klein.png: Content type: image/png
Achterkant.jpg: Size: 0
Start file uploading process on GCS for fileName: Zijkant.jpg id: 32df15b2-3ebe-4f3c-a040-11d8c1afe50f
[FAILED] Uploaded file is empty or size is 0
Klein.png: Size: 0
Zijkant.jpg: File extension: .jpg
Zijkant.jpg: Content type: image/jpeg
Start file uploading process on GCS for fileName: Hoofdfoto.jpg id: fb6b6992-7750-4ac2-af84-271885dc5f88
[FAILED] Uploaded file is empty or size is 0
Zijkant.jpg: Size: 0
Hoofdfoto.jpg: File extension: .jpg
Hoofdfoto.jpg: Content type: image/jpeg
[FAILED] Uploaded file is empty or size is 0
Hoofdfoto.jpg: Size: 0
2023-11-29 16:24:08.834 ERROR 5752 --- [ileUploader - 7] c.b.api.images.util.DataBucketUtil       : An error occurred while uploading data. Exception: 
api.images.exception.GCPFileUploadException: An error occurred while storing data to GCS: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.8000.8273688474402663459\work\Tomcat\localhost\api#v1\upload_65639dd4_178c_4f5f_8ffe_bc24d1b8cb4c_00000006.tmp (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at com.projectname.api.images.util.DataBucketUtil.uploadFile(DataBucketUtil.java:72) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.projectname.api.images.util.DataBucketUtil$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$905c2d1f.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
```

To summarize. We're uploading the images to google cloud services, then saving that into our database. Not everything's perfect but it's doing the job for now and if I do a successfull upload it also shows in our front end as it should.

I hope you can give me some possible solutions!

I tried to find out where the multipart file went empty/size 0. Which is the moment we enter the uploadImagesAsync function. I don't know how, or why. But I expected it to go wrong at the postman request part.

What weirded me out is that the when I tried several times, sometimes 1 out of 4 images would successfully upload but the others would not. And that, if I restart the project it actually works quite well.

My postman setup is quite simple. It's a form-data with "coverImage" with 1 picture and "images" with 3 pictures.